# jquery dynamically added .data() is undefined when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where I am setting some arbitrary data on a li element

```
function showCountries( data )
{
    for( var i in data )
    {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        $(li).html( '<a>' + i + '</a><span>&gt;</span>' );
        $(li).data('cargo', { state: data[i] });
        /* 
           right here, if I look at $(li).data('cargo').state in the debugger
           I see the data as expected
        */
        $('#countries').append( li );
        $(li).on('click', $.proxy( countrySelected, li ) );
    }
}
```

Later, in country selected, I want to get the cargo data.  But, it is undefined

```
function countrySelected()
{
    var country = $(this).children('a').html();
    // country is what I expect

    var cargo = $(this).children('a').data('cargo');
    // cargo is undefined here

    // I tried this too:
    var cargo = $('#countries li.selected a').data('cargo');
    // cargo is undefined here as well
}
```

What I am doing wrong?  Is this an issue with the .data() being set dynamically after the page is loaded?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
var cargo = $(this).children('a').data('cargo');
```

should be changed to this:

```
var cargo = $(this).data('cargo');
```

You set the data in the `li` element, not in the child `a`.

Answer (score 4):

You set your data on the `li` element, not the `a` element.

```
var cargo = $(this).data('cargo');
```